# Playing audio which source path contains "%" in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

So I have an audio file which name contains "%". So as far, I have the following tag `<audio src="test%320.mp3" controls></audio>`. However, I got an error while trying playing it, as if the file does not exist. Could anyone help me ?

I found some other thread where they used `encodeURIComponent` but I don't know how that work and tried it anyway. But that still won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The % is a special character

That is what is confusing Javascript. It is reading the `%32` as the ASCII code hex 32, which is decimal 50, i.e. the character "2". Therefore Javascript is looking for a file called "test20.mp3".

If you want to encode that, try using this to replace the string "test%320.mp3":

```
encodeURI("test%320.mp3")
```

That gives the result `test%25320.mp3` which, when you send to Javascript, will be correctly interpreted:

- `%25` will be interpreted as `%`
- `320` will be interpreted as `320`

So it will try to read file `test%320.mp3`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm gonna try that right away

Answer (score 1):

You are right with `encodeURIComponent`, use it like that:

```js
const fileName = "test%320.mp3";
const encodedFileName = encodeURIComponent(fileName);
document.getElementById("audioID").setAttribute("src", encodedFileName);
```

```html
<audio id="audioID" controls></audio>
```

The `%` will be url-encoded as `%25` and the file should play with the corrected name.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm gonna try this.